# select two tables on 1 query , but while getting 'id' from first table and use it on selection of second table

Tags: sql, select, union

```
SELECT status.*, 
       users.username 
FROM   status, 
       users 
WHERE  status.user_id = users.id 
UNION 
SELECT comments.user_id, 
       comments.commente, 
       comments.date_of_creation, 
       users.username 
FROM   comments, 
       users 
WHERE  comments.status_id = (SELECT status.* 
                            FROM   status 
                            WHERE  id = comments.statu_id) && 
                                  comments.user_id = users.id 
ORDER  BY status.id DESC;
```

Comment: Please use code markup (\`code\`) and newlines.

Comment: any particular rdbms?

Comment: Alrighty then...  There is a lot of "wrong" going on here.  Care to elaborate on what you're having issues with?

Answer (score 1):

I noticed user_id is common to all the tables. Do you simply require some joins:

```
SELECT s.*, 
    c.user_id, 
    c.commente, 
    c.date_of_creation, 
    u.username 
FROM users u 
inner join status s on s.user_id = u.user_id
inner join comments c on c.user_id = u.user_id 
ORDER  BY s.id DESC;
```